# How to fetch different columns from different tables using single query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

I need your humble help to a concept of web application. I want fetch different columns from different tables using single query. one column is same in all tables like pk_data(varchar). But I need different-different columns on basis `pk_data(varchar)` column. For example, I need user name from first table and address from second table and age from third table and cost from fourth table. But I need also use a where clause with `pk_data(varchar)` column.

We can understand this question in other way. I have a `HashSet` Variable that has a number of `String data(pk_data)`. I want fetch data on basis on this `HashSet` records.

And all strings of `HashSet` do not belong to all tables.

Please give suggestion to solve this issue.

Comment: you need to learn join queries

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha, I don't need to see a column data should be match to other table column or not

Comment: @user3860841 you have to post the table structure and some data if you want a proper answer.. i just threw something together as a general idea for now

Comment: this really is SQL 101 stuff, try http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Main_Page or http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ then this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins will help.

Comment: @Used_By_Already NEVER recommend w3schools... its bad and shows how to do stuff that is vunerable to sql injection. http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: if I had more power I would deem this as a duplicate of (many many before), it does not demonstrate any research either

Comment: @John Ruddell - ok, good to know (I wasn't considering anything beyond a join lesson)

Comment: @Used_By_Already yea I know/understand but just as a general rule if someone uses it and they do get help on one thing they will go back to there again for more help :)

Answer (score 0):

this is just pseudo code since I don't actually know whats in the tables and or what the table names are.. but this is the general approach you should take

```
SELECT u.username, a.address, p.age, b.cost
FROM users u
JOIN address a ON a.pk_data = u.pk_data
JOIN person p on p.pk_data = u.pk_data
JOIN bills b ON b.pk_data = u.pk_data
WHERE u.pk_data = "whatever"
```

Here I just called the tables users, address, person, bills.. you can change it to whatever you want. but the logic is there for joining the 4 tables

Answer (score -2):

Among other options, you can use an implicit inner join:

```
select
    first_table.pk_data, first_table.user_name, second_table.address, third_table.age, fourth_table.cost
from
    first_table, second_table, third_table, fourth_table
where
    first_table.pk_data = 'value'
    and second_table.pk_data = first_table.pk_data
    and third_table.pk_data = first_table.pk_data
    and fourth_table = first_table.pk_data
```

Comment: no you shouldn't recommend someone uses the old Ansi way of joining tables through the Cartesian Product.. there are many limitations when you dont use JOIN

Comment: I agree! Do not recommend the pre-ANSI dark ages, please

Comment: @JohnRuddell for example? MS SQL Server and Oracle, for example, will treat them as the same (same execution plan).

Comment: @Caffé, thank to suggestion but if any record will not match in first table and will match second table then no record is being fetched sir ji

Comment: @Caffé if you don't use a JOIN then what happens when you don't want to filter out some data? the Cartesian Product is not what you want but you want to not filter out some rows that arent in a table... can't do this this way... but you can with a LEFT JOIN. just one of MANY examples

Comment: @Used_By_Already You are not based upon facts. In MS SQL Server and Oracle they are executed in the same way, and the sintax is a meter question of habit.

Comment: @@Caffé, Dear Sir, I need data on basis HasSet records from these tables only.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I can use LEFT JOIN if I need it. The original question doesn't ask for it.

Comment: @Caffé so what happens when the OP who doesn't know anything about joins uses this and then needs to adapt it but cant? it shouldn't be recommended.. only used when you really know what you're doing.. and on top of that there is a JOIN keyword to join tables... keeps the query clean/easier to read.. keeps your join conditions on the join and the filtering conditions in the WHERE.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins -------------------- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/2009/09/30/the-old-inner-join-syntax-vs-the-new-inner-join-syntax/

Comment: @Caffé best practice is not determined by optimizers, the standard is the standard for a good reason, and the principles of this site are to write good standards based code whenever possible. To the extent, for example, that we prefer COALESCE() even though NVL() or ISNULL() might suit. Don't rely on judgments on how the optimizer interprets joins; If you go that far the Oracle optimizer will still use (+) - do you really want to go that far backward?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Now that you changed your point you made clear that it's not about limitation but only about subjective preferences, and even your references talk about preferences. Even readability is subjective as it many times is about culture. I think it's not reason to downvote an answer.

Comment: @Caffé it is **BOTH**.. i **didn't change** my point I **added to it**.. I just added the preference of readability along side the limitations to make another point. obviously the OP doesn't know much at all about joins so dont suggest something that is limited.

Comment: @JohnRuddell You didn't show any limitation of this syntax. You could show some references. I really would like to know it.

Comment: @Caffé I thought I already had with the LEFT JOIN.. I mean I can try and work up an example if thats what you mean. but you can't produce the same result when you want to join the data without filtering some in one table without a LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Used_By_Already Just to let you know, this syntax is not pre-ANSI, it's defined by ANSI SQL 89. I like ANSI SQL 92, but note that even the most respectable servers don't support all the standard even in these days.

Comment: @JohnRuddell As I wrote in my answer, it's a INNER JOIN and not a LEFT JOIN. You're taking a conceptual difference as a limitation.

Comment: @Caffé you're missing the point. first thing its not conceptual. its actual. for the scope of this post yes you don't need a left join... now what ive been saying the whole time is **this**.. the OP doesn't know joins. if the OP needs to change this or tweak it then he wont be able to. you should never assume that one query is only within the scope of what is posted.. it will be used/adapted. and there are limitations.

Comment: @Caffé if you want to get your reputation points back you can delete your answer and the points will be refunded :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks, John. I appreciate your worries but I don't see reason to do to that. Just because you say I "should never" do it or that doesn't mean you're right. My answer is exactly the same as yours with a different syntax. I've been using that syntax for 15 years and have never seen someone misunderstanding or having trouble to change it to fit other needs. I would even say that's a good syntax for beginners.Saying it's an evil syntax is just an opinion.